# Spring boot controller annotation for validation?

Tags: java, validation, spring-boot

Is there a way to write an annotation for a Spring Boot controller at the class level that can validate any String input to any of its methods? By any String input, I mean regular String inputs annotated with `@PathVariable` or `@RequestParam`, as well as those inside the objects annotated with `@RequestBody`, such as:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Car> update(@RequestBody Car car) {
    ...
}
```

Where the `car` instance has the following class definition:

```
public class Car {

    private String VIN;
    private String color;
    private Integer miles;

    //...
}
```

and an example JSON from the front-end could be:

```
{
    "color":"Blue",
    "miles":200,
    "VIN":"1234"
}
```

I want to ensure that all the Strings are validated against some arbitrary criteria (such as no illegal characters), and I wanted to do it using a clean, standard way, so that is why I want to know whether it is possible to create a controller annotation that can support this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Of course that is possible. Validation of the (JSON) input objects passed as `@RequestBody` is very straight forward using [Bean Validation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gircz.html) respective constraints, also take a look [here](http://codetutr.com/2013/05/28/spring-mvc-form-validation/).

A "higher hanging fruit" is doing that for all kinds of inputs in a generic way. Better think about if that is really needed and won't end in a maintenance hell if requirements drift apart. Nevertheless, an approach would be to use [Spring AOP](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html) for that.